# Exporting all display formulas from Lyx to separate SVG files on Mac

Tags: lyx, svg

I'm using Lyx on my Mac. I would like to use some sort of script which takes file.lyx as input and outputs SVGs of all of the display formulas in it.

This really should be automated and with no user interaction since there will be a LOT of these files with LOTS of display formulas in them.